# How to get hidden values in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to get text in text-area. But not able get it from xpath. How can I get it from any other way?

[image]

Comment: What does "not able" mean? Does the program crash? Can selenium not find the element? Can it find it, but the text is null? Does it find it but the text is different than you expect? How are you trying to get it? What exact keyword are you using?

Comment: i tried using 'GET TEXT' using xpath of 'Textarea', but it returns nothing Ex : ${text}=  GET TEXT  xpath=//textarea[@id='edit-text']
Result : ${text}= 'blank'
but i want to get text visible in screenshot as result....

Comment: Update: Referring to snapshot (Highlighted) the HTML dom tree doesn't have element to capture content inside the elements. *EX:*  I can read lable name as  *"Text"*, but not inside content in 'TextArea'. So my question is how can we capture the data, when html tree doesn't show elements for inside contents.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not using the correct xpath. There should be a way to identify the content that is there on the screen. The screenshot shows you are using firepath, so click on the data , or check the source for the divs and ids of the data being displayed, if you inspect that page you can find these details.